# Cannot get egress attribute from terraform data source aws_security_group

Tags: terraform, aws-security-group

I have a tf data resource defined.

```
data "aws_security_group" "this_sg" {
    filter {
        name   = "group-name"
        values = ["this_sg"]
    }
    vpc_id = "vpc-12345678"
}
```

I can pull out common arguments listed from here fine.
https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/security_group.html#name

```
${data.aws_security_group.this_sg.name}
${data.aws_security_group.this_sg.id}
```

but i can't pull the egress map

```
${data.aws_security_group.this_sg.egress}
```

my intention is to grab the list of cidr_blocks from within the egress map, likely through some horrendous mix of interpolations. But the egress argument can't seem to be pulled at all.
(i've checked the aws console egress cidr values are there)

```
Error: Error running plan: 1 error(s) occurred:
* Resource 'data.aws_security_group.this_sg' does not have attribute 'egress' for variable 'data.aws_security_group.this_sg.egress'
```

some ideas or work arounds would be much appreciated.

Comment: The [`aws_security_group` _data source_](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/security_group.html) doesn't have an egress attribute, as your error explains. You're looking at the docs for the [`aws_security_group` resource](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/security_group.html). It might help to understand _why_ you want the egress cidr blocks for the security group because there's probably a better way to do things.

Comment: I'm defining a sg group with a specific list of egress ips.

These ips happen to be already defined in another sg, so I'm trying to pull these.

Looks like I have to use pull the terraform_remote_state for the cidr blocks. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yes but the data source doesn't export these so you can't use it to get at them. You'd need to raise a feature request to get it to expose these or alternatively there might be a different approach you could use but it's impossible to tell without you explaining why you need them.